# List view Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view, it loads the personal details of some broadcasters.

If I click on this. it directs to another list view with some details.  When I try to scroll the view a force to close message appears.

List view is displayed by using LazyAdapter class and write some extra condition for second and third list view.

In first view scrolling has no problem. but all other view (second and third) scroll time error force to close how to solve this problem?

Date 23-03-2011
this problem is solved thanx for all comments

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What you want us to do for ya!?

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading data from a database? Do you access the database from the main thread? You might be unfortunate and perform a very time consuming database operation which causes the main thread (a.k.a the "GUI-thread") to become unresponsive. After a few seconds the system will throw the "Application Not Responding" dialogue.

Comment: data reading db and store in array send via Lazyadapter class constructor in the listing time no fetching from db.

Comment: why don't you share logcat of the crash.